# BOOST C++ segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, boost, runtime-error

Everytime I execute the program(NO errors BTW) it gives me a segmentation error. It says " Segmentation fault core dumped".  So I have added some cout<< statement to find out exactly where this happens, turns out it happens after the "Hives ended loop is done". I dont know why or how I can tweak my program to get it to work. I am using emacs on RedHat. this is my error:

```
[[A[rsridhar@stud13-h56 ~]$ ./ants
1
3 3 3 1 2
2 0 3 3 3
loope started
loop ended
loope started
loop ended
loope started
loop ended
2 1 4 4 4
loope started
loop ended
loope started
loop ended
loope started
loop ended
0 1 2 2 2
loope started
loop ended
loope started
loop ended
loope started
loop ended
hives started
0 1 2
hives ended
hives started
hives ended
hives started
hives ended
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I dont understand why at all.I wrote a similar program that worked fine on ym computer(this is the univs comp).Here is my program:

```
int main()
{
  typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, undirectedS, property<vertex_distance_t,int, property< vertex_index_t, int> >, property< edge_weight_t, int> > Graph;

  int no_trees,no_edges,start_tree,finish_tree,no_species,w,min_edge=0,answers[100];
  int hives[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    hives[i]=0;

  int test=0;
  cin>>test;
  int m=0;
  while(m!=test)
    {

      cin>>no_trees>>no_edges>>no_species>>start_tree>>finish_tree;   //get input
      Graph g(no_trees);

      property_map< Graph,vertex_distance_t>:: type distance;
      property_map< Graph,vertex_index_t>:: type index ;
      property_map<Graph, edge_weight_t>::type weights[10];
      for(int i=0;i<no_species;i++)   //constructor for weights property
    {
          weights[i]=get(edge_weight,g);
    }
      typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_desc;


      for(int i=0;i<no_edges;i++)   //input weights into weights array
    {
      int a=0,b=0;
      cin>>a>>b;
      edge_desc e;
      bool bol;
      tie(e,bol)=add_edge(a,b,g);
      for(int j=0;j<no_species;j++)
        {
              cout<<"loope started"<<endl;
          w=0;
          cin>>w;
              weights[j][e]=w;
              cout<<"loop ended"<<endl;
        }
    }
      for(int k=0;k<no_species;k++)
    { cout<<"hives started"<<endl;
      w=0;
      cin>>w;
      hives[k]=w;
      cout<<"hives ended"<<endl;
    }

      //find the minimum spanning tree for each of the weights in the graph
      cout<<"section 1";
      vector < vector< graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor> > p(10, vector<graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor>(num_vertices(g),0)) ;//predecessor vector

      cout<<"section2";
      //calling prim function on all diff prop_edges
      for(int i=0;i<no_species;i++)
    {
      cout<<"section3";
        prim_minimum_spanning_tree( g, hives[i], &p[i][0], distance, weights[i], index, default_dijkstra_visitor());
    cout<<"section4";
        }
      Graph g1(no_trees);
      property_map<Graph, edge_weight_t>:: type weight=get(edge_weight, g1);
      //join all the spanning trees into one
      int vertice_1,vertice_2;
      typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edge_itr;
      edge_itr ei,ee;

      for(tie(ei,ee)=edges(g);ei!=ee;++ei)
    { min_edge=0;
      cout<<"section5";
      vertice_1=source(*ei,g);
      vertice_2=target(*ei,g);
          for(int j=0;j<no_species;j++)
        { 
          if(p[j][vertice_1]==vertice_2 || p[j][vertice_2]==vertice_1)
        {
          if(weights[j][*ei]<min_edge)
            min_edge=weights[j][*ei];
        }
        }
      weight[*ei]=min_edge;
      bool bl;
      edge_desc c;
      cout<<"section6";
      tie(c,bl)=add_edge(vertice_1,vertice_2,g1);
    }
      std::vector<graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor> predecessors(num_vertices(g1));
std::vector<int> distances(num_vertices(g1));


      //call dijkstra algorithm()
      dijkstra_shortest_paths(g1,start_tree,predecessor_map(&predecessors[0]).distance_map(&distances[0]));

      answers[m]=distances[finish_tree];
      m++;
    }
  for( int i=0;i<test;i++)
    cout<<answers[i]<<endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Thank you in adance!

Comment: You should add `<<endl` to all `cout<<...` after the `hives`-section, as otherwise you don't even know where it really crashes.

Comment: that's a lot of code for us to read and understand. Where does it segfault? Have you attached a debugger?

Comment: It's also difficult to read. The indentation is very hard to figure out.

Comment: @FredLarson sorry for the identation.

Comment: @sam Miller it segfaults after the input.i tought it segfaults after the hives for loop.turns out it segfaults fater all the input.I just dont know which declaration or loop ive done wrong. I know there is a mistake with some memory.Just cant locate it.

Comment: <it now says segmentation fault:11